# Namespacing inherit method of parent object

Tags: javascript

Have trouble with namespacing and objects. I'm new on this so really confused.
I would like for one object in array to inherit parent object methods.

Here is my code:

```
 var obj = {

   arr1:['one', 'two'],
   arr2:[],

   init:function() {
       for(var x=0; x<this.arr1.length; x++) {
           this.arr2.push(new this.myfunc1(x, this.arr1[x]));
       }
       this.arr2[0].myfunc2();
   },

   myfunc1:function(x, name) {
        this.index = x;
        this.name = name;
   },

   myfunc2:function() {
        alert(this.index + ' ' + this.name);
   }

};

obj.init();
```

How can I inherit myfunc2 for my arr2 of objects? Is this used by prototype?

returns "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'myfunc2'"

Comment: I can understand your confusion. You are used to working with classes.  forget everything you know about classical OOP. JavaScript is object oriented but uses prototypes for inheritance. But in your case I don't think you need inheritance. Anyway, I will post a possible solution and in the mean time I suggest you catch up on some reading about JavaScript OOP ;-)

Comment: On further inspection, I'm getting confused myself. Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish? The way I see it you are trying to copy one array to another? Is `obj` your namespace or an object you want to reuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, you want to have the methods of "obj" in the objects you are creating at

```
this.arr2.push(new this.myfunc1(x, this.arr1[x]));
```

It's easy, the constructor of these objects is this.myfunct1() so you must assign the prototype object in the constructor's prototype property:

```
this.myfunct1.prototype = this;

for(var x=0; x<this.arr1.length; x++) {
    this.arr2.push(new this.myfunc1(x, this.arr1[x]));
}

// WORKS!!!
this.arr2[0].myfunc2();
```

And then "this" (obj) is the prototype of the created objects

Comment: Yes great! Thank you soo much! :) Saved my day, have a great one!